# Grep file modified in 24 hours unix

Tags: linux

I need to get the files which have been modified in the last 24 hours, and get owner and group of these files. How can I do that? The command

```
ls -lrt /dirpath | grep 'Util'
```

only gives this output:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      186 Apr 11 08:05 Util-04-11.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      185 Apr 12 08:05 Util-04-12.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      186 Apr 13 08:05 Util-04-13.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      186 Apr 14 08:05 Util-04-14.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      278 Apr 20 08:05 Util-04-20.log
```

Comment: What do you mean by _user and owner_?

Comment: i mean to check the owner and group of the file must be user

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
ls -ld /dirPath/*(m-1u[user]g[group])
```

would list the files owned by `user:group` and modified within the last 24 hours. `m-1` is for less than a day, you can also make it `mh-24`.

Add the `D` glob qualifier if you also want hidden files listed.

POSIXly:

```
find /dirPath/. ! -name . -prune -mtime -1 -user user -group group \
  -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

In bash:

```
find /dirPath -type f -user username -group groupname -mtime -1
```

This will just list the names, like:

```
file1
file2
...
```